# Не работает ссылка на проект в одном решении

Tags: c#

У меня есть одно решение с двумя проектами. В первом проекте есть класс, от которого нужно наследоваться во втором. Я добавил во второй проект ссылку на первый, но класс там не видно. В чем причина?

1

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Rectangle : Shape
        {
            public int height, width;
            public Rectangle(int height,int width) { this.height = height; this.width = width; }
            public override double Square { get { return height*width; } }
        }
    }
}
```

2

```
using ConsoleApplication1;

namespace Test_Access
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А какой модификатор доступа имеет класс? В правильном пространстве имен ищете?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Поставил паблики, подключил пространство но все равно не работает

Comment: сейчас выяснится, что первый проект под windows phone 7, а второй - asp.net core 2.1, а класс приватный и статический. Добавляйте всю нужную информацию в вопрос, пожалуйста

Comment: Оба проекта консольное приложение c#

Comment: оба проекта с одинаковой версией фреймворка?

Comment: покажите первый класс вместе с простанством имен

Comment: И второй ваш класс тоже покажите

Comment: @tym32167 Второй то что должен быть во втором проекте?

Comment: да, во втором проекте

Comment: У вас в первом проекте класс `Program` непубличный, поэтому его (и его содержимое) не видно во втором проекте.

Comment: @АндрейNOP +1 плюсую

Comment: Все благодарю за помощь

Comment: @АндрейNOP так мож ответ запостите?

Comment: Очередной вопрос о том, какая видимость по умолчанию у классов. Может где-то есть каноничная закрывашка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс `Rectangle` из первой сборки вложен в класс `Program` (см. [Вложенные типы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types)), поэтому доступ к `Rectangle` имеют только те, кто имеют доступ к внешнему для него классу. Но класс `Program` не объявлен как публичный (по умолчанию для классов область видимости — `internal`), поэтому он не доступен из второй сборки.

Comment: А можно ещё узнать как запустить его а то если во втором проекте написать static void Main() а в первом стереть то выдает ошибку CS5001

Comment: В solution explorer ПКМ по проекту — Set as StartUp Project

Comment: тогда еще выдает  CS0006

Comment: Другие сообщения об ошибках есть? Исправьте для начала их.

Comment: 1>------ Перестроение всех файлов начато: проект: ConsoleApplication1, Конфигурация: Debug Any CPU ------
1>CSC : error CS5001: Программа не содержит статического метода "Main", подходящего для точки входа.
2>------ Перестроение всех файлов начато: проект: Test_Access, Конфигурация: Debug Any CPU ------
2>CSC : error CS0006: Не удалось найти файл метаданных "C:\Users\jj\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe".

Comment: Можно ещё про [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) добавить.

Comment: @Hujuk, вот сначала CS5001 исправьте